# Looking for a C/C++ implementation of the Hungarian method for real-valued cost matrix

Tags: optimization, c++, combinatorics

I am looking for a C/C++ implementation of the Hungarian method for solving the linear assignment problem with real-valued cost matrix.

Some implementation I found, such as [this one](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~stachnis/misc.html), only work for integer costs :(

Any suggestions are very appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it work to multiply your cost by a big constant and take the integer part of it ? so that you could directly use the link mentioned in the question, at the expense of loosing a little bit of precision, if you can afford it.

Comment: Go to [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org) and download the ["clue" package source](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/clue_0.3-50.tar.gz).  The LSAP code contains a C implementation of the Hungarian method.

Answer (score 2):

This one seems to work great for me:

https://github.com/mcximing/hungarian-algorithm-cpp